# English reference for the Brauer-Kuroda formula

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions, translation

I'm currently trying to understand the Brauer-Kuroda formula.

Although there are many recent papers on the formula but they seem to be purely algebraic.

They say that original analytic approach is much easier and short.

So I hope to find a reference on the original proof of Brauer-Kuroda formula using the formula for the residue of Dedekind zeta function.

But the papers of Kuroda, Brauer are in German.

So is there any good reference for the formula in 'English' that just explains the papers of Kuroda, Brauer? In other words, the shortest reference in English.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Section VIII.7 in Fröhlich-Taylor, Algebraic Number Theory, Cambridge University Press.